# Stripe Payment Integration React Native + Laravel

Tags: php, android, laravel, react-native, stripe-payments

I want to integrate stripe payment in react native. Application's back-end is in Laravel.
This is what I came to know. We send amount, currency to the back-end that Intents Stripe payment and return a client_secret that is used in react native to send it to stripe and made payment successful.
This was the controller code as provided

```
  Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

  $intent = PaymentIntent::create([
     'amount' => ($request->grand_total - $request->coupon_discount) * 100,
      'currency' => $request->currency
  ]);
  $client_secret = $intent->client_secret;
```

but at $intent  error is returned

```
[Error: Request failed with status code 500]
```

then I tried reference: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents

```
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('KEY_HERE');

      \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
         'amount' => 1099,
         'currency' => 'usd',
         'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
         'confirm' => true,
       ]);
```

but the same error
Then I tried reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'KEY_HERE'
);
$stripe->paymentIntents->create([
  'amount' => 2000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
]);
```

actually I don't have knowledge about Laravel. If any one can suggest me what's wrong.

In stripe logs page post request is now successful after removing

```
'confirm' => true,
```

but still error is same 500.
[image: Stripe Logs Image]

Comment: Wrap the first example in a try/catch and in the catch, examine the `$e->getMessage()` to see the actual error message.

Comment: 1/ are you seeing any requests make it out to Stripe, on your Logs page in the Dashboard? https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/ 
The 500 error you linked seems to not be a Stripe related error. 2/ what errors are you seeing? is there an error message?

Comment: yes, it is wrapped with try/catch but  there is not error from thrown by try/catch just 500 error is returned in react-native

Comment: @hmunoz I updated question please have a look

Comment: so the Stripe request is working fine (from your Logs page screenshot), so the issue is coming from the rest of your Laravel code presumably, after your PaymentIntent create call. What code is called after your PaymentIntent create code?

Comment: I removed all the code even just left two Stripe Intent lines but still same error